# Fill NA with character in list

Tags: r, lapply, tidyr

I have some data as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
thisdata <-  data.frame(numbers = c(1,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,5,6)
                     ,letters = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'))

otherdata <-  data.frame(numbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I am looking to split 'thisdata' by the letters column, merge the two lists to 'otherdata' by the numbers column, then fill letters NA with the corresponding letter in that list. So:

```
out <- split(thisdata , f = thisdata$letters )
out2 <- lapply(out, function(x) merge(x,otherdata,by="numbers",all = TRUE))
```

However, I can't get the 'fill' function in tidyr to work within the lapply

```
out3 <- lapply(out2,function(x) fill(x$channel))

 Error in UseMethod("fill_") : 
  no applicable method for 'fill_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

This is the output I'm after, but would rather perform the calculation within the list format:

```
out4 <- rbindlist(out2)

out5 <- out4 %>% 
  fill(letters) %>% #default direction down
  fill(letters,.direction = "up")

   numbers letters
 1:       1       A
 2:       2       A
 3:       3       A
 4:       4       A
 5:       5       A
 6:       6       A
 7:       1       B
 8:       2       B
 9:       3       B
10:       4       B
11:       5       B
12:       6       B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill` expects a data frame as first parameter, try `fill(x, letters)` or `x %>% fill(letters)` with `magrittr` pipe:

```
out3 <- lapply(out2,function(x) fill(x, letters))

out3
#$A
#  numbers letters
#1       1       A
#2       2       A
#3       3       A
#4       4       A
#5       5       A
#6       6       A

#$B
#  numbers letters
#1       1       B
#2       2       B
#3       3       B
#4       4       B
#5       5       B
#6       6       B
```

---

A simpler method is use `tidyr::complete`:

```
thisdata %>% 
    complete(numbers = otherdata$numbers, letters) %>% 
    arrange(letters)

# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   numbers letters
#     <dbl>  <fctr>
# 1       1       A
# 2       2       A
# 3       3       A
# 4       4       A
# 5       5       A
# 6       6       A
# 7       1       B
# 8       2       B
# 9       3       B
#10       4       B
#11       5       B
#12       6       B
```